# Compare AssertNull in an if statement

Tags: java, junit, compiler-errors, assertion

In my JUnit testing assert statement, I want to print something if the test passes. It currently throws an error because it returns type `void`? Is there a method where this is viable?

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Calendar;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object x = b();
        if (assertNull(x) == null) {
            System.out.println("123");
        }
    }
    public static Object b(){
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not how JUnit tests are written!

Comment: why you written main method if it is junit test?

Comment: i know, i exported this piece as an example from my code so people can just paste it in and try to work with it quickly @Seelenvirtuose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`assertNull` terminates the test with a failure if the argument is not `null`. If you want to print something out if the test **passes**, you could just have it after the `assertNull`:

```java
assertNull(x);
// If x is not null, the test ends here, and the following statement isn't reached
System.out.println("123");
```